# Не удаётся получить файлы

Tags: phpstorm, ftp

Настроил FTP. Нажимаю справа Remote Host...под названием проекта началась загрузка в итоге она закончилась и каталоги сервера не отобразились. В чём может быть проблема?

Использую последнюю версию PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Необходимо было включить пассивный режим